# What is another way to prove the least amount of pence, nickels, dimes and quarters that guarantees making any change exactly?

Tags: combinatorics, alternative-proof, combinatorial-proofs

In United States, there are four common coins people carry,

\begin{align*}
1 \text{ Penny} &= \$0.01 \\
1 \text{ Nickel} &= \$0.05 \\
1 \text{ Dime} &= \$0.10 \\
1 \text{ Quarter} &= \$0.25 \\
\end{align*}

Define making the *exact change* as not getting any coins back from the cashier, i. e., paying the fractional dollar in exact coins. E. g., one buys two gallons of milk for $\$10.19$ then making the exact change here means paying the fractional dollar as a dime, a nickel and four pence.

Some people (like myself) always pay the ceiling of the total bill and end-up with an ever increasing pile of coins under the armrest of their cars. To remedy that, I started thinking if I could assure myself of making the exact change each time, I will be better encouraged to actually take some of those coins with me.

Clearly, the more random coins one carries, the greater the probability of making the exact change but,

> What is the least amount of pence, nickels, dimes and quarters that guarantees making any change exactly?

Taking a greedy approach, you can conclude that you need 3 quarters since if you needed four then you are paying in a dollar, 2 dimes since three means you can use a quarter, 1 nickel since two of them mean you can use a dime and 4 pence since five would mean you can use a nickel.

Now I want to prove this in a more algebraic way where 4 pence, 1 nickel, 2 dimes and 3 quarters fall out as a solution of something. Let $\lceil x_1\rceil, \lceil x_2\rceil, \lceil x_3\rceil, \lceil x_4\rceil$ be the number of pence, nickels, dimes and quarters then,

1. Assume that we will on average need 2 of each type of coins.
2. The coins will have to sum up to more than $\$0.98$ since otherwise we can't make $\$0.99$.

One way I have done it is using this system,

\begin{align*}
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 &> 8 && \text{By assumption 1}\\
x_1+5x_2+10x_3+25x_4 &> 98 && \text{By observation 2}\\
x_1+x_2 &> 4 && \text{By assumption 1}\\
x_1+5x_2 &> 6 && \text{By an observation similar to 2}\\
\end{align*}

Solving this system does yield,

$$
\lceil x_1\rceil, \lceil x_2\rceil, \lceil x_3\rceil, \lceil x_4\rceil
=
4, 1, 2, 3
$$

But I find this proof to be kinda hand-wavy and obvious in its reverse-engineering. Does someone see a better, more elegant algebraic/combinatoric proof here? Maybe something with the binomials or a generating function?

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Is there a more elegant proof for this argument?" says nothing about the subject of the question, it's a useless title. See the "Choose a good title" section in [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, that's better

Comment: "Assume that we will on average need 2 of each type of coins."  Um... why?

Comment: I think the most elegant expression is a modulo proof.  If $M\equiv p\pmod 5; 0\le p < 5$ then you need at least $p$ pennies (no american says "pence" BTW) but no more and $p\le 4$. If $M\equiv 5n + p\pmod {10};0\le 5n+p<10\implies n=0,1$ then we need $n$ nickles but no more $n\le 1$. If $M\equiv 10d + 5n+p\pmod{25};d\le 2$ then we need $d$ dimes and no more.  If $M\equiv 25q + 10d + 5n + p\pmod{100};q< 4$ then we need $q$ quarters and no more.  And all else are bills.

Comment: @fleablood how did you get $d\leq 2$? $10d + 5n + p \leq 24 \Rightarrow 10d + 9 \leq 24 \Rightarrow 10d \leq 15 \Rightarrow d  \leq 1.5$?

Comment: $p \ne 4; p \le 4;$ and $n\ne  1; n\le 1$ so if $n=0$ we may need $d=2$

Comment: Checkout my answer, see if you'd chance anything or if you agree?

Comment: For a general approach to the "Change-making problem" see the two links to papers on the subject, in the comments to the question and in an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/106317/573047).

Comment: So my day dreams have research done on them already? Marvellous!

Answer (score 1):

The following [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/) model is a machine-wavy view on your problem:

```
int: TotalCoins = 10;

%  how many coins do wee keep per value?
array[1..4] of var 0..TotalCoins: x;

%  we don't want to keep more coins than necessary
constraint sum(x) == TotalCoins;

constraint forall(s in 1..99) (
      exists(c1 in 0..x[1], c5 in 0..x[2], c10 in 0..x[3], c25 in 0..x[4]) (
        s == (1*c1 + 5*c5 + 10*c10 + 25*c25)
      )
    );
```

For $10$ coins, it comes up with your solution. For less than $10$ coins, no solution exists.

A solution without Nickles:

```
x = [9, 0, 2, 3];
```

A solution without Dimes:

```
x = [4, 4, 0, 3];
```

A solution without Quarters:

```
x = [4, 1, 9, 0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @fleablood's comment, here is a proof using moduli,

*Proof.* Let $t\in\mathbb{N}$ be any dollar amount in cents and $c \in \{5, 10, 25, 100\}$. Define $\max(\mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z})$ as the smallest element of the largest residue class in $\mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z}$ then,
$$
\max(\mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z}) = c-1
$$
Observe that any $t \mod c$ can be paid entirely using only the coins worth less than $c$. Since we know that,

$$
\max(t \mod c) = \max(\mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z})
$$
We list the needed minimum number of coins of each type to make $\max(\mathbb{Z}/c\mathbb{Z})$ for each $c$,

\begin{align*}
\max(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}) = 5-1 &= 4  && \text{4 Pence.} \\
\max(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}) = 10-1 = 9 &= 5+4  && \text{1 Nickel, 4 Pence.} \\
\max(\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}) = 25-1 = 24 &= 10+10+4  && \text{2 Dimes, 4 Pence.} \\
\max(\mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}) = 100-1 = 99 &= 25+25+25+10+10+4  && \text{3 Quarters,} \\
& && \text{2 Dimes, 4 Pence.} \\
\end{align*}

Therefore, any $t$ can be made exactly with 3 Quarters, 2 Dimes, 1 Nickel and 4 Pence. QED.