# Greedy algorithm

Tags: algorithms

Prove or disprove that the greedy algorithm for making change always uses the fewest coins possible when the denominations available are pennies (1-cent coins), nickels (5-cent coins), and quarters (25-cent coins).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: [Previous relevant question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/looking-to-understand-the-rationale-for-money-denomination)

Answer (score 2):

Since the each coin divides the face value of every larger coin, a single larger coin will always represent an integer multiple of smaller coins.

Answer (score 0):

After giving out the maximal number of quarters, there will be $0-24$ cents remaining.  Then there will be at most 4 nickels to give out.  After giving out nickels greedily, there will be $0-4$ cents remaining, so there will be at most 4 pennies to give out.  Now, can you prove that we cannot rearrange our change to use fewer coins?