# The coin change problem in the quantitative  way

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

Today,I came across this problem:

> Suppose you have a currency, named miso, in three denominations, $1,
>  10$ and $50$. In how many ways can $107$ miso be given in this
>   currency if you have access to infinite number of coins of the said
>   three denominations only?
>
> $a)15 \quad \quad \quad b)16 \quad \quad \quad \quad c)17 \quad \quad
>  \quad d)18 \quad \quad \quad \quad e)19$

I identified that this is the [coin change](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change) problem and I am aware of the dynamic programming formulation for this, and till now my solution looks like [this](http://ideone.com/FhBuW) which is not at all intended by the problem setter, I am just wondering is it possible to solve this just by pencil-paper way? Of-course I don't want to do the dynamic programming steps in pencil paper.

Comment: If you can expand $\dfrac1{(1-x)(1-x^{10})(1-x^{50})}$ into series, and take the coefficient of $x^{107}$ ...

Comment: See [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=CxSoZcNymacC&pg=PA171) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67329).

Comment: @J. M.:Are you really telling me to expand that series in an exam?

Comment: That's why I gave you the link to Google Books. It shows how to do this cleverly, instead of differentiating 107 or so times...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra 7 miso have to be made up out of 1 coins, so let's ignore them.

Now ask how many 50 coins you use to make up 100 miso. Clearly you use 0, 1 or 2. Once you've decided that, then deciding how many 10 coins determines the number of 1 coins that you need. So we can easily enumerate all the possibilities by hand:

- Zero 50s, in which case the number of 10s is in {0,1,...,10} (there are 11 possibilities)
- One 50, in which case the number of 10s is in {0,1,...,5} (there are 6 possibilities)
- Two 50s, in which case the number of 10s is 0 (one possibility)

So there are 1 + 6 + 11 = 18 ways of making 107 miso out of 1s, 10s and 50s.