# Number of partitions of an integer, if the partitions are no larger than $2$

Tags: integer-partitions, inclusion-exclusion

> Find an explicit formula for the number of partitions of a positive integer $k$ into parts no larger than $2$?

I was thinking about it and worked on it, I've come up with $1^k+2^k= 3^n$.

Comment: What does "1^k,2^k= 3^nth power" mean?

Comment: Sorry I mean to put + sign between 1+2=3

Comment: You've come up with a false identity. And I really don't get why some people seem to have an affection for writing $1^k$ instead of $1$, when they are evidently the same thing.

Comment: So what would the formula be then?

Comment: Try some small cases and see if you recognize the numbers.  There is a recurrence, as the last number added to make $k$ can be either a $1$ or a $2$.  You could also look at Mark Bennet's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269615/how-many-ways-can-133-be-written-as-sum-of-only-1s-and-2s)

Comment: -amWhy so it would be P_k+1=P_k+P_k-1=F_k+1+F_k by= F_k+2