# Change the money

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making Change for a Dollar (and other number partitioning problems)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15521/making-change-for-a-dollar-and-other-number-partitioning-problems)

The problem is:

> How many are ways to change one dollar using coins: 5,10,20,50 cents?

The method is completely clear to me. Generating function is: $$\frac{1}{1-x^5}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^{10}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^{20}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^{50}}$$ and we are looking for the coefficient before $x^{100}$ in series expansion of this function. But I don't know, how to do it quickly? Of course, I can decompose this function to simple fractions, but it is really brute force approach and it will take a lot of time. Are there any good general methods for finding coefficients before $x^n$ in series expansions of functions? It is often very useful..

Comment: [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+for+1%2F%28%281-x^5%29%281-x^10%29%281-x^20%29%281-x^50%29%29+at+x%3D0)'s one method (click on "More Terms" a couple of times).

Comment: You mean Taylor expansion? Right, but for big $n$ it fails unless given function has a "pretty" Taylor expansion.

Comment: calculate $\frac{1}{100!}\frac {d^{100}}{dx^{100}}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^5}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^{10}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^{20}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^{50}}\right)$ and set $x=0$

Comment: @J.M. thanks a lot!! Now I see, this method with recursion for each coin is brilliant. This is what I needed.

Comment: If you've managed to figure out what to do, you might want to write an answer to your question...

Comment: Or rather to the other question, since this one is likely to get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I described a method that satisfies me in that earlier question.