# What is the number of nonnegative solutions of a linear equation?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the number of solutions of a linear equation? for example look at this equation:

$X_1+X_2+...+X_n=r$

The number of solutions is the following formula, because the way of choosing $r$ objects from $n$ distinct objects when repetition is allowed is going to be this formula

$C(n+r-1,r)$

Now what about this equation

$2X_1+4X_2+X_3=24$

What is the number of solutions?$X_i$ is non negative integer

Comment: What are $x_i$? integers? rationals?

Comment: they are all integers

Comment: Let's fix $x_1$ to some value, say $x_1=4$, so we get the equation $x_3=-4x_2+16$. How much solutions does this equation have? If you are asking about natural numbers, then it's different.

Comment: @Galc127 $X_i$s are non negative integer, this problem is in the discrete mathematics

Comment: This sounds like the NP complete subset sum problem.

Comment: @Irvan This problem is asked in the discrete math book of Grimaldi at the end of the first season!

Comment: Well, the equation you asked is of a very special form where all the coefficients divides each other. There's a polynomial algorithm (which can be translated to a formula) to solve this form.

However, if the coefficients can be arbitrary, I'm pretty sure even finding out whether it has a solution is NP complete.

Comment: $X_3$ must also be even, so it can be represented by $2k$, which then gives us $$X_1 + 2X_2 + k = 12$$

Comment: @amWhy no it is not at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to "making change" type problems, such as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15521/making-change-for-a-dollar-and-other-number-partitioning-problems).

They can easily be solved with recurrences or generating functions.

So for example in this case, consider the coefficient of $x^{24}$ in the expansion of $\dfrac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^4)}$ which is $1+x+2 {x}^{2}+2 {x}^{3}+4 {x}^{4}+4 {x}^{5}+6 {x}^{6}+6 {x}^{7}+9 {x}^{8}+9 {x}^{9}+12 {x}^{10}+12 {x}^{11}+16 {x}^{12}+16 {x}^{13}+20 {x}^{14}+20 {x}^{15}+25 {x}^{16}+25 {x}^{17}+30 {x}^{18}+30 {x}^{19}+36 {x}^{20}+36 {x}^{21}+42 {x}^{22}+42 {x}^{23}+49 {x}^{24}+\cdots$ so giving the result $49$.

Answer (score 2):

The equation is $2x_1+4x_2+2x_3=24$.

We can show that $x_3$ has to be divisible by 2. Say $x_3=2y$ we get the equation $2x_1+4x_2+2y=24$.

Dividing by 2 we get $\displaystyle x_1+2x_2+y=12 \rightarrow x_2=\frac{12-x_1-y}{2}$.

We can conclude that both $x_1$ and $y$ are even or both are odd.

If they are even then $x_1=2k \ , \ y=2m$ and we get $\displaystyle x_2=\frac{12-2k-2m}{2}=6-k-m \rightarrow k+m+x_2=6$. You can use your first formula.

If they are odd then $x_1=2k+1 \ , \ y=2m+1$ and we get $\displaystyle x_2=\frac{12-(2k+1)-(2m+1)}{2}=5-k-m \rightarrow k+m+x_2=5$. You can use your first formula.

Does this answer help?

Comment: You answer is very customized to this problem what if the coefficients are 2,3 and 5? does this work this well?

Comment: In the general case of equation of the form $\displaystyle a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3+...+a_kx_k=C$ we can use generating functions - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function.