# How many ways can you make change for a dollar?

Tags: problem-solving, generating-functions

This is a generic generating functions problem, and you are left with 1/(x-1)(x^5-1)....(x^50-1) however now I want to find the coefficient of the x^100 term of this expression... how can I do this or do I have to use partial fractions which will take ages...

Comment: I guess you'd have to use complex numbers... but this will take forever...

Comment: I am guessing your "..." may have $1,5,10,25,50$ cent coins, though it rather depends on which dollar you are assuming.

Comment: Multiplying out $(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{100})(1+x^5+\cdots+x^{100})\cdots(1+x^{50}+x^{100})$ is not that difficult with a CAS or even a spreadsheet

Comment: yeh that's right, which dollar you are assuming???

Comment: And yes that's easier than complex numbers ect...just not very elegant

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar#Economies_that_use_a_dollar

Comment: Zimbabwe dollar

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15521/making-change-for-a-dollar-and-other-number-partitioning-problems

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.maa.org/frank-morgans-math-chat-293-ways-to-make-change-for-a-dollar.  This site shows how the answer is obtained with just some intelligent counting.  Despite the title of the site Frank Morgan suggests $292$ ways, not counting a dollar coin.