# How many ways are there to write $173$ as a sum of squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, sums-of-squares

Q. How many ways are there to write $173$ as a sum of squares of natural numbers?

A friend of mine recently asked me this question, and I haven't been able to figure it out fully. I know that $$2^2+3^2+4^2+12^2=2^2+5^2+12^2=2^2+13^2=\sum_{k=1}^{173} 1^2=173.$$ So, there are atleast four ways to write $173$ as a sum of squares. However, I haven't found any other solutions. I also haven't been able to prove that these are the only solutions. If we had something like $a^2+b^2=173$ where we were restricted to only $2$ numbers in the LHS, perhaps we could use modular arithmetic and find all solutions. However, the question doesn't say "How many ways are there to write $173$ as a sum of two squares?". The fact that the LHS could have anywhere between $2$ and $173$ natural numbers complicates things a bit. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am adding the "contest-math" tag as my friend said that he saw this question on a video that was intended for olympiad practice. However, I haven't been able to find the video.

Comment: Do it like you would the famous [change for a dollar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027067/how-many-ways-can-you-make-change-for-a-dollar) problem.  Your "coins" have value $\{1,4, 9, 16, \cdots, 169\}$ and your "dollar" is worth $173$.

Comment: if $s=x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2<173$ then this can be augmented to a sum of squares adding up to $173$ bei adding some $1^2$ to $s$

Comment: Agreed on terminology, if it was two squares and since $173 \equiv \, 1 \: \text{Mod} \, 4$ there will only be one set of two integers.

Comment: Should say, there are lots and lots of solutions.  $173=13^2+1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2$ for instance.  I did it fast (and, therefore, possibly incorrectly) and  got an answer over $1,000$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python code

```
target = 173
squares = [i**2 for i in range(1, int((target)**(1/2))+1)]

ways = {i: 0 for i in range(target+1)}
# Every sum starts at zero (if there are no squares added)
ways[0] = 1

for sq in squares:
    for total in range(sq, target+1):
        # We can add the square to the previous total-sq to get total
        ways[total] += ways[total - sq]

print(ways[target])
```

returns that there are 13027 ways to get 173 as a sum of squares.

See also [A001156](https://oeis.org/A001156).

Comment: @lulu no I am not, for `target=10` we get an answer of 4 and $10=3^2+1^2$$=2\cdot 2^2 + 2\cdot 1^2 $$= 2^2 + 6\cdot 1^2 $$= 10\cdot 1^2$. The main loop over `squares` ensures that the possibilities of something like $13^2$ are always added later than $2^2$.

Comment: My mistake.  Since I invoked the "change of a dollar problem" I mentally reset the target number to $100$.  When I put in the correct value of $173$ my answer matches yours.  [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Taylor+expansion+product%5B%281-x%5E%28n%5E2%29%29%5E%28-1%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C13%7D%5D%5D+).  I'll delete my first comment.