# How many ways can he pay the $107$ shikels

Tags: elementary-number-theory

David went to the market yesterday, he bought some stuff by $107$ shikels, when he opend his wallet to pay for the stuff, he saw different types of money, $1$ shikel, $10$ shikel, and $50$ shikel. How many ways can he pay the $107$ shikels?
Assuming that there are enough amount of all types of money.

Comment: The problem "how many ways to make change for a dollar" is well known, and you can easily find discussions online ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15521/making-change-for-a-dollar-and-other-number-partitioning-problems) for instance).  The same techniques will apply here.

Comment: have you heard about generating functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1\cdot x+10\cdot y+50\cdot z=107$$
$$x+10y+50z=107$$
where $x,y,z\ge0, x,y,z \in \mathbb Z$

$z\le 2$

1) Let $z=2$, then $$x+10y=7$$
Then $x=7, y=0$

$$(x=1, y=0, z=2)$$

2) Let $z=1$

3) Let $z=0$

Can you finish?

Comment: I think the answer is $18$ ways , isn't it?