# All possible combinations from a list to sum to X

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, additive-combinatorics

I have a maths question I can't wrap my head around.

Assume you have a container of volume X. You need to fill it with 4 types of boxes A, B, C, D of different sizes. A is the smallest box, B is three times bigger than A, C is 30 bigger than B and D is twice as big as C.

So:
 B = 3A,
 C = 30B = 90A,
 D = 2C = 60B = 180A

The capacity of the container is 40D (i.e. the container can hold a maximum of 40 size D boxes at one time).

Question: How many unique combinations of boxes can you have to fill the container? What is the distribution of the number of boxes? (Calculate min, max, mean and 95th percentile)

Comment: One would think that the shape of the boxes matters, e.g. what if the container is *really* narrow and *really* long?

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter. The container can hold a max of 40D or 80C or 2400B or 7200A or any combination of them.

Comment: You can get inspiration here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15521/making-change-for-a-dollar-and-other-number-partitioning-problems