# Find all combinations of numbers from {x1,x2,...,xn} that sum of to sum S

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, set-partition

Given a list of some integers, I would like to find every combination that can be summed to some sum S.
For example for the sum S=16, and the list of integers I={3,4,5}, I'd expect to get:

5,4,4,3 (=16)
5,5,3,3 (=16)
4,4,4,4 (=16)

How do I go about finding such lists for any given S, with any list of integers S?

Note, I can be a set of any integers they don't have to be sequential. 
Also note, I do understand this has to do with partitions, and have done reading to the best of my ability, but I have failed to fully understand how to make sense of this.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm?

Comment: I'm looking to understand how to construct such an algorithm. 
So far, I've been able to figure out how to calculate the amount of possible partitions, but I don't understand how figure every possible way to "fill" those partitions.

Comment: You can just do it recursively. Take one of the integers $n$ in the set, consider the maximum number $m$ of the integer we can include, and run the algorithm with new sum $S-kn$ and integer set without $n$ for each $k$ from $0\to m$.

Comment: I think I got it! Let me actually try to implement it, and see if I spoke too soon :)

Comment: This is the same as the famous [making change for a dollar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15521/making-change-for-a-dollar-and-other-number-partitioning-problems).

Comment: there is various of branching problems of Subset-Sum and knapsack with dynamic programming for them. i guess you should look alos for these problems, and you'll find what you look for (nobody's says those algorithms gonna be run fast though)

Comment: Don, I ended up successfully using your suggestion for algorithm. Many thanks!