# Number of different types of n-permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, permutation-matrices

Any $n$-permutation can by decomposed into the product of disjoint cycles. Assume there are $N_k$ k-cycle, the we can call $(N_1,N_2,\cdots,N_n)$ the type of a given permutation.

My question is how many different types are there, i.e. the number of nonnegative integer solutions of equation
$$N_1+2N_2+3N_3+\cdots + nN_n = n$$

Is there a closed form solution? I know how to solve equation in the form of
$$N_1+N_2+\cdots + N_k = n$$

But for this question, it is quite unclear to me. Any hints would help. Thanks.

Comment: This is similar to the "making change for a dollar" problem, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15521/making-change-for-a-dollar-and-other-number-partitioning-problems). Here, $n$ is the amount you want to reach, using coins of values $1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Comment: The number of nonnegative integer solutions to the equation 
$N_1+2N_2+…+nN_n=n$ is equal to the number of [integer partitions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$. There is no closed form for this number, but there are some complicated infinite summations which yield approximations.

Comment: Thank you both for the references.